# VIM CTRL+B/F does not move back/forward one screen instead renders ^B / ^F

Tags: vim, keyboard-layout

When I try to use vim's INSERT mode and want to navigate the cursor with  the editor yields `^B` instead moving the cursor back. Can anybody tell me what I have to rebind to make this work again. Also for .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<C-B>` / `<C-F>` commands only work in *normal mode*. In *insert mode*, the literal control characters (rendered as `^B` / `^F`) get inserted.

You can define mappings that enable scrolling in insert mode:

```
inoremap <C-b> <C-\><C-o><C-b>
inoremap <C-f> <C-\><C-o><C-f>
```

The `<C-\><C-o>` executes a single normal mode command from insert mode.

Alternatively (at least in GVIM), `<PageUp>` / `<PageDown>` also work in insert mode out of the box.